# Which one is more preferable, linestring or tsrange?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

For representing a continuous time range in PostgreSQL, which one is more preferable, linestring (using just x axis) or tsrange?

Comment: I don't see how a geographic data type would be useful for a "time range". Given you extremely short description I'd say a `tsrange` is what you are looking for. But without more details this is impossible to answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your comment! In PostGIS User Conference 2016, representing time spans with linestrings is regarded as one of  the top 10 problems solved by PostGIS'. [link] (http://www.postgis.us/presentations/PGConfUS2016_PostGISTop10.pdf)